# Is it correct to ask "Between who and who does s/he stand?"

Tags: sentence-construction, wh-questions

Assume that there are three girls standing in line, girl A, girl B and girl C.

Obviously, girl B is standing between girl A and girl C.

But how do I ask where girl B stands?

***1: Between who and who does girl B stand?***

or

***2: Between who does girl B stand?***

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a speaker of US English, I would probably say

> Between who is she standing?

or

> Between who does she stand?

**who** can refer to more than one person, so it isn't really necessary to say "who and who".  Technically, it should be **whom**, because you're asking about the object of a sentence, not the subject of one:

> Between **whom** does she stand?

but *whom* is not very common these days and many people just use *who* all the time.

If you want to be really specific in your question, you can ask

> Between **which two girls** does she stand?

Answer (score 0):

You simply ask

> "Where does girl B stand?"

To which the answer will be:

> "Between girl A and girl C."

The point to note here is that girl B (or any other girl for that matter) may not always stand between two persons. In such a case, the aforesaid question is still valid. Only the answer may change, something like:

> "Beside girl C."